# how to get offsetX that Relative to the parent div when i click one div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

this is my code:

```
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;background:red;word-wrap:break-word;">
            <div id="b" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

the script is :

```
$( "#b" ).draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
$('#a').click(function(e){
        alert(e.pageX)
        //return false;
    })
```

the e.pageX is  Relative to the `window` ,

how to get the x,y Relative to the parent div ?

the demo is here :http://jsfiddle.net/KwYjr/2/

thanks

Answer (score 4):

See the following documentation for information on the Event object in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

You will see that it normalises (makes the same over browsers) some of the properties, but not all.  The one you need is `.offsetX`.

http://jsfiddle.net/KwYjr/3/

Note that `.offsetX` is not always defined in some browsers.  There is usually an alternate variable in the event that can be used.  Otherwise get the `.offset()` position of the element you want the value from and then use `.pageX` with it.

Try using `e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft`: http://jsfiddle.net/KwYjr/7/

Comment: use regular offset and top and left property's they should work fine.

Comment: In Firefox they do not exist, so have to be calculated as stated.